# Change the default font of Back button in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the default font of Back button in UINavigationController to a custom font

```
UIFont *myCustomFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:18];
```

How can I set this custom font to the Back Button? I've browsed through other answers to similar questions in this site with no success.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347428/469614

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:
        @{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor blackColor],
         UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset:[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
         UITextAttributeTextShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor],
         UITextAttributeFont: myCustomFont
        }
         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I placed this code in `viewDidAppear` and it didn't work. Should I be placing this code somewhere else?

Comment: Downvote for copypasting this answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535507/change-font-of-back-navigation-bar-button

Comment: deprecated and a copy